# Special Character does not displays in gridview from SQL database with Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Well I have tried all you people suggested but the problem remain same

let me tell you in brief:

Form Name : ​**AuzineForum.aspx**

Has 1 GridView which displays all the field  from the database using ​ select * from QF

its working good , index is also working , the gridView Has Button and onClick I  open new Form ​AuzineForumAnswer.aspx​ ..OK

I want to pick one record from  ​AuzineForum.aspx​ and display on AuzineForumAnswer.aspx  as well as it happens here in http://stackoverflow.com (we click on threads then the new page opens which has the question and answer  on which we clicked previous) ...ok

so On AuzineForum.aspx's Button the code is

```
Button lb = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
            if (row != null)
            {
                int index = row.RowIndex; //gets the row index selected


                Label AID1 = (Label)ForumQuesView.Rows[index].FindControl("AID1");
               Label AID2 = (Label)ForumQuesView.Rows[index].FindControl("AID2");
               Label AID3 = (Label)ForumQuesView.Rows[index].FindControl("AID3");
               HyperLink Question = (HyperLink)ForumQuesView.Rows[index].FindControl("Question");
               Label Questiontags = (Label)ForumQuesView.Rows[index].FindControl("Questiontags");
               Label Askedby = (Label)ForumQuesView.Rows[index].FindControl("Askedby");


               Response.Redirect(String.Format("AuzineForumAnswer.aspx?Question=" + Question.Text + "&Questiontags=" + Questiontags.Text + "&Askedby=" + Askedby.Text + "&AID1=" + AID1.Text + "&AID2=" + AID2.Text + "&AID3=" + AID3.Text, Server.UrlEncode(Question.Text), Server.UrlEncode(Questiontags.Text), Server.UrlEncode(Askedby.Text), Server.UrlEncode(AID1.Text), Server.UrlEncode(AID2.Text), Server.UrlEncode(AID3.Text)));
```

I had passes so many many parameter becuase of accuracy......

Now when I run it and click on the button so its open ​AuzineForumAnswer.AuzineForumAnswerand shows that record very well but problem occurs when the qtags field has "#" type of data like here tags( ​C#, GridView, etc) so, ​ when the tags field has the data includin "#" chracter then it gives "​Object refrence not set to Instance of an object " and if the qtags has normal data like ( specialcharacter gridview sql C ) then it open AuzineForumAnswer.​aspx​ and show data without error

the code behind of AuzineForumAnswer.aspx  is below

```
 protected void GetAllData()
        {
            string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuzineConnection"].ConnectionString;


            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = sqlconn.CreateCommand())
                {
                   sqlcomm.CommandText = "Select * From QF where Question='" + Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Question"].ToString()) + "' And qtags='" + Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Questiontags"].ToString()) + "' And UserFullName='" + Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Askedby"].ToString()) + "' And AID1='" + Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["AID1"].ToString()) + "' And AID2='" + Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["AID2"].ToString()) + "' And AID3='" + Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["AID3"].ToString()) + "'";

                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    try
                    {
                        sqlconn.Open();

                        ForumQuesView.DataSource = dt;
                        ForumQuesView.DataBind();

                        ForumQuesView.AllowPaging = true;

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Status.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

NOW I ALSO DO NOT UNDERSTAND What the problem here because only qtags and question is two field in which user allows to store data as they want, the ​question  ​is text and qtags and all are the char field but problem is not in database the problem is here with the character #

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see what sql statement is created? Post that sql statement.

Comment: debug, get the query and run it in sql server. I nothing goes wrong then there must be problem with your initialization of any object regarding this-- " Object reference not set to instance of an object"

Comment: Dear Polin, I also agree with you but what I am saying is that ...I have many rows in qtags columns , I get no error by clicking any row , but the row who has "#" character they gives the error and when I went to SQL server directly to change inside the row then it gives error "Binary data would be truncated " now this error comes when the limit exceed but all is well , I do not understand where the mistake I did

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your sql statement to include parameters and see if that works.

What you have now is not only difficult to maintain and causes errors but it’s prone to SQL injection attack quite easily.

```
sqlcomm.CommandText = "Select * From QF where Question=@Question And qtags=@Qtags And UserFullName=@UserName And AID1=@AID1 And AID2=@AID2 And AID3=@AID3";

sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Question", Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Question"])));
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qtags", Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Questiontags"])));
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Askedby"])));
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AID1", Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["AID1"])));
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AID2", Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["AID2"])));
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AID3", Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["AID3"])))
```

;

Comment: now its give this error when I used parameters , I have all field in [char]and question field has [text] ......Parameterized Query '(@Question nvarchar(300),@Qtags nvarchar(14),@UserName nvarchar(' expects parameter @UserName, which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

As I know the query is fine even if you using # in the condition.

I doubt for a moment, then I tried this query

```
Select * From QF where Question='question 1'
And qtags='tag #1';
```

those query still run smooth and return the record.